# Selected text doesn't appear on the UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Whenever I click on a `UITextField`, a list of contacts appear and when a contact is clicked, the phone number should appear in the textfield that was clicked. I currently have 3 textfields and each time I select a contact, it updates only the first textfield even if for example I have selected the 2nd textfield. How do I go about fixing it so that the phone number appears in the corresponding textfield that was selected?

I'm using Xcode 10 and I think that the issue is arising from the `func setNumberFromContact`

```
    @IBOutlet weak var phonenumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phonenumber1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phonenumber2: UITextField!


        func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {


            let phoneNumberCount = contact.phoneNumbers.count

            guard phoneNumberCount > 0 else {
                dismiss(animated: true)
                //show pop up: "Selected contact does not have a number"
                return
            }

            if phoneNumberCount == 1 {
                setNumberFromContact(contactNumber: contact.phoneNumbers[0].value.stringValue)

            }else{

                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Select one of the numbers", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

                for i in 0...phoneNumberCount-1 {
                    let phoneAction = UIAlertAction(title: contact.phoneNumbers[i].value.stringValue, style: .default, handler: {
                        alert -> Void in
                        self.setNumberFromContact(contactNumber: contact.phoneNumbers[i].value.stringValue)
                    })
                    alertController.addAction(phoneAction)
                }
                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {
                    alert -> Void in

                })
                alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

                dismiss(animated: true)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

        func setNumberFromContact(contactNumber: String) {

            var contactNumber = contactNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
            contactNumber = contactNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "")
            contactNumber = contactNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "")
            guard contactNumber.count >= 10 else {
                dismiss(animated: true) {
                    self.presentAlert(alertTitle: "", alertMessage: "A maximum of 10 contacts allowed per session", lastAction: nil)
                }
                return
            }

            phonenumber.text = String(contactNumber.suffix(10))

        }

        func contactPickerDidCancel(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController) {

        }




}

extension SelfTestTimer: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }


    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        if textField.hasText{
            //dont do anything

        }else{

        contactPicker.delegate = self
        self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        return
    }
```

Comment: Adding a little more information to @RajeshKumarR's answer: the reason only one of your text fields is updating is because of this line: ```phonenumber.text = String(contactNumber.suffix(10))```. You're changing only ```phonenumber``` text field. His solution should work fine.

Comment: Yeah it totally worked. Thanks a lot for the input @Marcel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your solution is updating only one text field is because you're updating the text of only that text field. In this line `phonenumber.text = String(contactNumber.suffix(10))` you change only `phonenumber`'s text. A good solution would be as follows:

Create a temp UITextField to store selected text field reference

```
@IBOutlet weak var phonenumber: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var phonenumber1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var phonenumber2: UITextField!
var currentTextField: UITextField?
```

And use that text field in text field delegate methods

```
extension SelfTestTimer: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        currentTextField = nil
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField.hasText{
            //dont do anything
        }else{
            currentTextField = textField
            contactPicker.delegate = self
            self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        return
    }
}
```

Assign selected contact number in that text field

```
func setNumberFromContact(contactNumber: String) {
    var contactNumber = contactNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
    contactNumber = contactNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "")
    contactNumber = contactNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "")
    guard contactNumber.count >= 10 else {
        dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.presentAlert(alertTitle: "", alertMessage: "A maximum of 10 contacts allowed per session", lastAction: nil)
        }
        return
    }
    currentTextField?.text = String(contactNumber.suffix(10))
}
```